# What does the expression "Round up below the cut" mean?

Tags: expressions

Or what's its equivalent?

The whole sentence was: ["Let me give you a round up below the cut"](http://www.goodreads.com/author_blog_posts/5422832-why-i-want-bitcoin-to-die-in-a-fire)

Comment: The whole sentence was: "Let me give you a round up below the cut"

Comment: Can you provide some context?  I can think of 3 different situations this might be used:  "A boss may have concluded an evaluation of his employees intending to lay off those below some defined ranking so he wants to gather all those below the cut(off).  OR  A group of hikers may decide to gather just below the pass through the mountain.  OR a statistician may decide to adjust upward all the numbers he has that are below some threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate elements here. The first *(round-up)*, which simply means *summary*, is a relatively common and established (informal) usage.

But *below the cut* is an unusual turn of phrase that probably only started to appear with the Internet. *Cut* here is jargon/shorthand for [cut-off [point]](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cut-off-point) *- the limit at which something is no longer applicable.*

Basically, the writer expects that his text will be *cut off* (terminated prematurely) in whatever context the reader will initially be reading it.

In this *specific* context, it's Charles Stross's blog page. He wants to get his summary in before the point on that page where it says something like *Click here to read the rest of this article*.

---

**Edit:** After posting this, I realised that logically, one might expect ***before*** the cut in OP's context. Have a look at [How to do a text cut/”read more” on tumblr](http://childishgrin.tumblr.com/post/1123400859/how-to-do-a-text-cut-read-more-on-tumblr), where it says...

> *Everything of this post after the “read more” line will be put **under a cut.***

I'm not sure it really makes much difference to the overall meaning, but presumably ***the cut*** in OP's case actually means *the **above** text, which has been "cut & pasted" from another source*.